# TextBlock Visibility Binding when to another textBlock's width cross the Maxwidth

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a requirement in my WPF application I have two TextBlocks on horizontal position

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding FileName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxWidth="450" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding FileExt}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxWidth="50" Visibility="{Binding }" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
            </StackPanel>
```

In ViewModel I have this two properties set `FileName` and `FileExt` but I want the textBlock2 which is Binded to `FileExt` Properties, It will be shown only when the textBlock1 width cross the `MaxWidth` (Size 450), then only TextBlock2 will be visible.

May I know what will be my approach? The first textblock is actually a fileName. Suppose the filename is "BOOKOFWPF.pdf" then it does not cross the max length so I don't need to show the FileExt textBlock, but if the file name is long enough to fit in the then as it's `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` I have implemented so in this case I need to show the FileExt text block.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, **which was not easy** :

Maybe you should do it in the ViewModel.

```
public bool HasCrossed { get { return this.FileName.Length > XXX; } }
```

For your second textblock's visibility :

```
[...]
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
[...]
Visibility="{Binding HasCrossed, 
             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Don't forget to raise `PropertyChanged` for the `HasCrossed` property in your FileName's setter.